# Safari get stuck on facebook

Tags: macos, safari, facebook

I am using MacBook pro and the problem is that safari gets stuck when the Facebook is open and also I open another tab and come back to the Facebook tab, then safari get stuck and the cursor becomes colorful round so I have to quit Safari and open it again. when Facebook is not open and I open multiple tabs, then safari doesn't get stuck.

any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can happen if you were uploading an image for a facebook post, were browsing for a file to upload, and forgot to finish it. 
Clear the Safari cache and restart your system, that should solve the issue.